# Regular expression for separating strings

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string

> Long string 1 [sucess 50] long string 2 [apple 5 banana 20 orange 75]
>   long string 3 [failure: 100]

Now I want to split it into three strings:

1. Long string 1 [sucess 50]
2. long string 2 [apple 5 banana 20 orange 75]
3. long string 3 [failure: 100]

inside [] there could be one or more instances of combination of a string and a number, and the number is from 0 to 100.

How this can be done with regex in python?

Comment: You just want to add newlines?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Seems you won't need regular expressions, just split the string by character  `]`.

Answer (score 3):

No need for regular expressions in such a simple task. Just use Python's built-in `str.replace()` method like so:

```
your_str = your_str.replace(']', ']\n')
```

To split it and get a list, use `your_str.split(']')`

But if you really want regex or the string inside the brackets can contain more brackets, you can try this:

```
import re

your_str = "Long string 1 [sucess 50] long string 2 [apple 5 banana 20 orange 75] long string 3 [failure: 100]"

your_str = re.sub(r'\[(.+? [0-9]+)\] ', r'[\1]\n', your_str)

print(your_str)
```

The following code produces this output:

```
Long string 1 [sucess 50]
long string 2 [apple 5 banana 20 orange 75]
long string 3 [failure: 100]
```

But this is going to be a string. To get a list of strings, you can then simply split by newline like this:

```
your_str.split('\n')
```

Comment: sorry for not being clear enough. the long string could also contains [] and (). so the input would be:
“(condition (apple) [harvest 100] (in (street_number) [2110 3211 3299 2672 5087]) [clean 50] (or (in (phone_number) [3213335512 3113337843 2332224083 3221112625]) (in (apt_size) [1030 2165]) (in (parcel_id) [3133 8314 8886])) [charge 100])”
what I want:
“(apple) [harvest 100]”
“(in (street_number) [2110 3211 3299 2672 5087]) [clean 50]”
“(or (in (phone_number) [3213335512 3113337843 2332224083 3221112625]) (in (apt_size) [1030 2165]) (in (parcel_id) [3133 8314 8886])) [charge 100]”

Comment: I think I always want to split by [<string> <a number between 0 and 100>]. I dont know how it can be done in regex

Comment: @WeiXiao please, edit your answer with this string and the desired output, it's hard to read in the comments

Answer (score 0):

```
In [79]: import re

In [80]: my_string = "Long string 1 [sucess 50] long string 2 [apple 5 banana 20 orange 75] long string 3 [failure: 100]"

In [81]: re.findall(r'([^\[]*\[[^\]]*\])(?: ?)', my_string)
Out[81]: 
['Long string 1 [sucess 50]',
 'long string 2 [apple 5 banana 20 orange 75]',
 'long string 3 [failure: 100]']
```

How the regex works:

```
([^\[]*\[[^\]]*\])(?: ?)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/pH92LSnQn9168BW5)

Detailed explanation at: https://regex101.com/r/oS1oL8/1

Comment: sorry for not being clear enough. the long string could also contains [] and (). so the input would be: “(condition (apple) [harvest 100] (in (street_number) [2110 3211 3299 2672 5087]) [clean 50] (or (in (phone_number) [3213335512 3113337843 2332224083 3221112625]) (in (apt_size) [1030 2165]) (in (parcel_id) [3133 8314 8886])) [charge 100])” what I want: “(apple) [harvest 100]” “(in (street_number) [2110 3211 3299 2672 5087]) [clean 50]” “(or (in (phone_number) [3213335512 3113337843 2332224083 3221112625]) (in (apt_size) [1030 2165]) (in (parcel_id) [3133 8314 8886])) [charge 100]”

Comment: I think I always want to split by [<string> <a number between 0 and 100>]. I dont know how it can be done in regex

Comment: @WeiXiao Please create a new question with these requirements.